# Navigating through different forms in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, navigation, windows-forms-designer

I recently started working on an application with windows forms using C#. To navigate through the different forms I am using:

```
        Form Form_name = new Form ();
        Form_name .TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        panel1.Controls.Add(Form_name);
        Form_name.Show();
```

The current setup is that I have the main menu form where you then navigate to a upload photo form. But after uploading an image in the upload photo I want to show the next form. But because we now are working in another form we cant use:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
panel1.Controls.Add(Form_name);
```

Because panel1 is referenced in the first form. I tried to create a public class to clear it but had no success.

My questions come down to:

- Is there a better method to navigate through different forms/windows?
- Can we create a public function to clear the panel in the first form?

MainMenu.cs

```
private void mainMenu1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ME_Upload ME_UploadConstruct = new ME_Upload();
    ME_UploadConstruct.TopLevel = false;
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    panel1.Controls.Add(ME_UploadConstruct);
    ME_UploadConstruct.Show();
}

private void mainMenu2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IndividualEditor individualEditor = new IndividualEditor();
    individualEditor.TopLevel = false;
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    panel1.Controls.Add(individualEditor);
    individualEditor.Show();
}
```

}

ME_Upload.cs

```
private void ME_UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
            opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg; *.png; *.gif)|*.jpg; *.png; *.gif";
            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ME_ImageEditor ME_ImageEditorConstruct = new ME_ImageEditor();
                ME_ImageEditorConstruct.TopLevel = false;
                panel1.Controls.Clear(); ///Not Working
                panel1.Controls.Add(ME_ImageEditorConstruct);  ///Not Working
                ME_ImageEditorConstruct.Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first piece of code still looks wrong both in terms of syntax errors and logic. Are you sure you want add the form to the panel's child controls? Usually one would add the panel to the form's child controls. Even usualier, one would do that by creating a subclass of Form using the Form designer. If you're used to some other GUI library where you have to create all the widgets in code, then your approach makes sense, but not in Winforms.

Comment: You should use a `UserControl` instead of `Form`. A userControl can be designed like a Form in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        menu1.TopLevel = False
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        Panel1.Controls.Add(menu1)
        menu1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        menu3.TopLevel = False
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        Panel1.Controls.Add(menu3)
        menu3.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        menu2.TopLevel = False
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        Panel1.Controls.Add(menu2)
        menu2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```